# Partitioning a rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

We are given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, where $m>n$, and a symmetric orthogonal projection matrix $P$. The projection matrix has $p$ nonzero eigenvalues and $p<n$. Is it possible to find a transformation that partitions $A$ into blocks of rows that are and are not affected by $P$, while preserving the value of $\text{trace}(APA^T)$?

The partitioning should have the form $$A' = \begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y\end{bmatrix},$$ where $X$ is $p\times n$ and $Y$ is $m-p \times n$.
The effect of the projection matrix can be expressed $$A'P = \begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y\end{bmatrix}P = \begin{bmatrix}X \\ YP\end{bmatrix}.$$

**First attempt:** The trace is preserved under a similarity transform, i.e. $$\text{trace}(APA^T) = \text{trace}(WAPA^TW^{-1}).$$ Now the question is if it is possible to find such $W$ that satisfies $$WA=A'.$$

Here is where I get stuck though. Maybe it is possible to construct $W$ from the eigenvectors of $P$?

Comment: Do you know about the [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Canonical_forms) of a projection matrix?

Comment: Skimming through this section quickly, I must confess that no... I somehow thought that 'canonical form' of a square symmetric matrix would be its eigendecomposition, i.e. QDQ^T, where Q is orthogonal and D is the matrix of eigenvalues.

Comment: You didn't state a premise that $P$ is symmetric. If you add that premise, the partition that you want is possible. In this case, the canonical form of $P$ reduces to $I_m\oplus0_s$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I meant that $P$ is an orthogonal projection, which is symmetric. Let me correct this.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized you wanted it for rows and it only works for columns. I hope my answer isn't completely useless to you -- perhaps you already knew how to do it for columns...

Comment: I still appreciate your answer. I knew that it could be done for the columns, but it was not clear to me if it could be done for the rows... Your answer suggests that it cannot, which is helpful.

Comment: Another way to see that this is a natural thing for the columns but not for the rows is to note that for the columns, this is a matter of integer dimensions -- there's an eigenspace of dimension $m$ with eigenvalue $1$ and one of dimension $s$ with eigenvalue $0$, and you can assign $m$ columns to one and $s$ to the other. For the rows, there's nothing to count. Every row has a (possibly zero) component in each space; there's no natural way to count how many rows should be invariant and how many annihilated; even if you tried to measure this with some norm, it wouldn't generally be an integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79850/discussion-between-j-k-and-joriki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing this question with [@joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) in the [chat above](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79850/discussion-between-j-k-and-joriki), I formulated the problem more precisely. It turns out that this partitioning can be done and in many different ways. One would, however, have to make more assumptions in order to find an explicit solution.

In brief, the partitioning can be accomplished by first transforming $A$ into a matrix that has zeros in the last $m-n$ rows. This is done by factoring as $A=QL$, where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $L$ is a lower trapezoidal matrix. Then the first $n$ rows of $L$ can be transformed in a way that $p$ of them are invariant under the given projection and $n-p$ would be annihilated.

Comment: Great. Thanks for writing this up. I think you can accept it as the answer in two days or so. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: And thanks to you for a very stimulating discussion about this!